# enforce captcha with google recaptcha v2

Tags: python, django, recaptcha

I had implemented google recaptcha v1 for a portal. I now want to implement google recaptcha v2 for a portal. I am able to display the widget. I now want to check the validation part in python django backend. Is there a way to enforce and have the captcha images displayed, for development purpose, so that I could check the code flow for validation.

Comment: There is no restriction on using captcha in localhost...! How far you tried ?

Comment: No. What I want is google recaptcha to think me as a robot and pose the images for me to enter. How can i enforce that?